# How to use tf.session.run() for testing (not updating network's parameters)?

Tags: validation, session, testing, machine-learning, tensorflow

Normally I use tf.session.run() for training my networks, and use eval() for getting test accuracy or loss. But I see people also use session.run() for getting testing result, which is very strange for me. I thought tf.session.run() is only for training, not testing.

Is there any secret under tf.session.run() that I didn't know?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tf.session.run()` is meant to run one or several TF operations, or evaluate TF tensors, possibly even mixing of these two categories.

When called on a tensor, it will basically evaluate it just like `eval()`. You can use it for training, with `sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=train_data)`, which will update your variable values, because this is what train_op does. However, if you call `sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=data)`, it will evaluate the value of the `accuracy` tensor when the input values are those given by `data`, regardless of whether this is training, validation or testing data, and it will not change the variable values, since you're just evaluating a tensor, not running an operation that changes variable values.

So `tf.session.run()` is much broader than you thought indeed, it is the usual way to run inference or evaluate your performance, even at test time !

You can even do multiple things at once, which avoids doing the forward pass multiple times on the same input:

```
_, loss_value, accuracy_value = sess.run([train_op, loss_tensor, accuracy_tensor], feed_dict=data)
print('Loss value: %f' % loss_value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @gdelab! So the function actually does only what we requires in the train_op?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you call `sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=train_data)`, it runs the `train_op` once and does only that, yes. (if you have an enormous graph but `train_op` only uses and affects a small part of it, only this small part will be run). Similarly, if you call `acc_value=sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=data)`, it will not run `train_op`, besause it does not need it for `accuracy`, so it will not change the variable weights.

Comment: Yea, I got it now. Thank you! Your explanation is clear!